# how to print a flat file list windows

Tags: file, list

I thought this would be easy to do, but I can't wrap my head arond it.

I need to print a report of all the files in a dir, including sub dirs on a windows server.

Folder01\File01.txt
Folder01\File02.txt
Folder02\File01.txt

etc

Is there an easy way to spit that out to the screen?

Obviously i would pipe to file eventually, but I am still trying to figure out how to get a flat file list of a windows hierarchy printed out

Comment: Provide the code you have tried to get a quicker answer.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't give a language.  There are many options.  The simplest is probably `dir/b/s` in the Windows shell.